# FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate not triggering delegate methods

Tags: ios, facebook

Login and Logout is working correctly.
According to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3)

> "Your app can get notifications of login results or logout events. To
>   do this assign a delegate to FBSDKLoginButton that confirms to
>   FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate protocol."

I've added the [FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate) to my view controller which has the following property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *FacebookButton;
```

and the .m (implementation) file has:

```
@interface firstVC ()
<FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@end
```

but the problem is that the FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate is not calling:

```
- (void)  loginButton:  (FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:  (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:  (NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"facebook login button test");


}
```

and on logout is not calling:

```
- (void) loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{
  NSLog(@"facebook logout button test");
}
```

Additionally I have declared the aforementioned methods in the header between @interface and @end

Comment: In appdelegate ..had you declare anything in openurl method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to make sure the button's class was FBSDKLoginButton instead of UIButton, which I had already done:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *FacebookButton;
```

Once I did that and implemented the two aforementioned classes in the question, then the fix was to set the button delegate to self on viewDidLoad in the implementation file:

```
[FacebookButton setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Follow the obj-C naming convention, the correct naming is "faceBookButton"

Answer (score 0):

I think ConfusedDeer's answer is not valid with current releases. Because even documentations are seems to be outdated.

The work around I found, was using;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkLogIn) name: FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

snippet above, inside the application:openURL called by Facebook App.
Within the selector I made the necessary work after login.

Note: Same function will be called at every access token state change, so you should be backing up this code with your own logic.
At least until Facebook fixes the document or the code.

Answer (score -1):

add those lines to your viewdidload

```
[_loginFaceBook setReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]];
[_loginFaceBook setDelegate:self];
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
```